# Chat application in Android using quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox

I am developing a chat application to build a huge community in F&B sector.

I have downloaded Q_municate app code (uses quickblox) and it is running good on my device. Only thing is that I am looking to implement a logic to connect users. Let me try to explain here.

There are two types of users "A" and "B" which would be interacting with each other.

1. 'User of type A' will fill up a form with his preferences
2. On the basis of these preferences the application should filter 'users from type B' and send notification to them with chat request.
3. Now whoever 'user from type B' accepts the chat request first of all, will start chatting with 'user of type A'.

Please let me know if this logic can be implemented with the existing Q_municate code.

Answer (score 0):

The right algorithm could be:

1. Create a custom profile on CustomObjects module and store any additional information for user http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android
2. Filter these profiles via CustomObjects API
3. Use Chat API to send notifications to needed users to starts a chat http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample